# How to add subscribe functionality to rails app (view related)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'd like to allow my users to ability to subscribe to other users newsletters. I've got the associations all setup I'm just having trouble coding the actual "Subscribe" button/functionality so that when a user clicks it they will be subscribed to that chosen newsletter and subsequently receive emails from it.

How might I code this functionality to actually "subscribe" the users?

I have the following models & associations in place:

**newsletter.rb**

```
class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates_presence_of :image, :name

  scope :for, ->(user) do
    if user 
      Newsletter.all
    end
  end

end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
         :validatable

  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_newsletters, through: :subscriptions, class_name: "Newsletter"
  has_many :newsletters

  validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :password, on: :create         

end
```

**subscription.rb**

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :newsletter
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :newsletter
end
```

I have a dashboard controller, with an index action where I'd like to display the feed of newsletters, and have a subscribe button under each newsletter. How might I code this subscribe functionality?

Please advise!

Comment: You might want to mention in your question-title that, you are looking for help on the View-aspect of the app.

Comment: Hi Satya, I've attempted your above steps it's about 80% there pleae help with what I'm doign wrong. See answer below

Answer (score 1):

From the above coding, I assume you are already familiar with ROR & JS stuff. So, I will not start writing code, rather suggest the flow/approach.

Ideally, you have to use an Ajax functionality.

Following is the Pseudo code:

1. In the index page, for each NewsLetter, add a Subscribe button/link.
2. Clicking the button/link should trigger an Ajax request. The payload being the ID of the news-letter.
3. Define a Controller#Action and route for the same. This action is what is triggered by the above AJAX call.
4. Define the action to subscribe the current-user to the corresponding news-letter.
5. In the response (ideally, JS), replace the button with UnSubscribe button.
6. Similarly, define an Unsubscribe functionality.

Comment: This is a great workflow, if you'd be willing to provide some actual code examples for namely, steps 2-4 I would gladly accept your answer! :)

Comment: Hi @SatyaKalluri , I've attempted your above steps it's about 80% there pleae help with what I'm doign wrong. See answer below

Comment: Hey Sonny Black, ping me on satya_techsavy on Skype. We can collaborate and resolve it. And then, post the fix/answer here.